# Multiple Ajax Calls on every 200ms causing delay after running few minutes

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, real-time

I'm using Ajax **Get** method for fetching data from my Controller through JsonResult Method which is getting data from my **MarketModel** which is filled by another class using WEBAPI

```
public JsonResult GetIndicesJsonObject()
{
    List<MarketModel> MarketModel = SinkClass.IndicesList;
    return Json(MarketModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have 10 methods like this I'm calling these methods on every 200ms.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        myVar  = setInterval("showdata2()", 200);
        myVar1 = setInterval("showindices()", 200);
        myVar2 = setInterval("showenergy()", 200);
        myVar3 = setInterval("showOil()", 200);
        myVar4 = setInterval("showCots()", 200);
        myVar5 = setInterval("showAgri()", 200);       
        myVar6 = setInterval("showIntra()", 200);
        myVar7 = setInterval("showPGold()", 200);
        myVar8 = setInterval("showPagri()", 200);
        myVar9 = setInterval("showFinan()", 200);

    });
```

It run's smoothly for few minutes but after few minutes it starts hanging. I have seen in Network the ajax calls slows up. That's why I'm getting data late.
Below is the code for one of ajax method I have, there are 10 methods like this.

```
 function showindices() {
        showTime();
        var data = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Employees/GetIndicesJsonObject",
            type: "Get",
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index) {


                    var a = document.getElementById(data[index].Contract);

                    if (a == null)
                    {
                        $('#indices tbody').append("<tr class='child' id= " + data[index].Contract + " onclick='MakeCellEditable(this)'>  <td class='Symm' id='sss'>  <b>" + data[index].Contract + " </b> </td>  <td class='BVol'>" + data[index].BidVolume + "</td>  <td id='idbid' class='bid'  >" + data[index].Bid + "</td> <td class='ASK' id= " + data[index].Ask + " >" + data[index].Ask + "</td> <td class='AVol'> " + data[index].AskVolume + " </td>   <td id='LAST' class='LAST'>" + data[index].last_ + "</td> <td class='VOLUME'>" + data[index].volume_ + "</td> <td class='totalT'>" + data[index].Total_Volume + "</td>  <td class='hig'> " + data[index].High + "</td > <td class='lw'>" + data[index].Low + "</td> <td class='change'> " + data[index].Change + "</td><td class='changeP'> " + data[index].Change_Per + "</td> <td class='open'>" + data[index].Open + "</td> <td class='closeP'>" + data[index].Close + "</td> </tr >");

                    }


                    else
                    {


                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("BVol")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("BVol")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("BVol")[0].innerHTML != data[index].BidVolume) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("BVol")[0].innerHTML = data[index].BidVolume;
                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Bid) {


                            if (a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML > data[index].Bid) {
                                a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                                a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Bid;
                                //; a.getElementsByClassName("sym")[0].style.color = "red";
                            }


                            else {
                                a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].style.backgroundColor = "palegreen";
                                a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Bid;
                                //  a.getElementsByClassName("sym")[0].style.color = "green";
                            }

                        }

                        else if (a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].innerHTML == data[index].Bid) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("bid")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        }


                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Ask) {

                            if (a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML > data[index].Ask) {
                                a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                                a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Ask;
                            }

                            else {
                                a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].style.backgroundColor = "palegreen";
                                a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Ask;
                            }

                        }



                        else if (a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].innerHTML == data[index].Ask) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("ASK")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("AVol")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("AVol")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("AVol")[0].innerHTML != data[index].AskVolume) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("AVol")[0].innerHTML = data[index].AskVolume;
                        }


                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("LAST")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("LAST")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }


                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("LAST")[0].innerHTML != data[index].last_) {


                            a.getElementsByClassName("LAST")[0].innerHTML = data[index].last_;

                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("VOLUME")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("VOLUME")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("VOLUME")[0].innerHTML != data[index].volume_) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("VOLUME")[0].innerHTML = data[index].volume_;
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("hig")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("hig")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("hig")[0].innerHTML != data[index].High) {

                            a.getElementsByClassName("hig")[0].innerHTML = data[index].High;


                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("lw")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("lw")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("lw")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Low) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("lw")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Low;
                        }

                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("open")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("open")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("open")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Open) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("open")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Open;
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("closeP")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("closeP")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("closeP")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Close) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("closeP")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Close;
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("totalT")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("totalT")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("totalT")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Total_Volume) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("totalT")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Total_Volume;
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("change")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("change")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("change")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Change) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("change")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Change;
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("changeP")[0].innerHTML == 0) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("changeP")[0].innerHTML = "";
                        }
                        if (a.getElementsByClassName("changeP")[0].innerHTML != data[index].Change_Per) {
                            a.getElementsByClassName("changeP")[0].innerHTML = data[index].Change_Per;
                        }
                    }
                    //  if (document.getElementsByClassName("Symm").innerHTML != null) 
                    //  $('#display-table tbody').append("<tr class='child' id= " + data[index].fksymbol + "><td >" + data[index].fksymbol + "</td><td >" + data[index].changeprice + "</td></tr>");

                });

            },
            error: function (msg) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the server is trying to protect itself against a DoS attack and throttles your requests. Another possibility is that the server is fast enough but the client creates requests faster than it can handle the replies, thus throttling itself. You might want to try random intervals between 300 and 800ms (timing is subject to trial and error).

Comment: You also might like to make a single call rather than 10 *simultaneous* calls